# What is wrong with my mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run some mysql code and I keep getting an error and I am not sure what I need to do to correct it.

The code I am trying to run is:

```
$key_amount = 1000;
for ($i = 0; $i < $key_amount; $i++) {
 $key = sha1(sha1($i));
 $query = "INSERT INTO keys (key) VALUES ('".$key."')";
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Could not make key");
}
```

The specific error I get is this: (When I do it in Sequel Pro)

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$key_amount = 900' at line 1

When I try to run it via a PHP file I get this error:

> Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/path/webapps/path/keygen.php on line 6
>
> Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/path/webapps/path/keygen.php on line 6
> Could not make key

Comment: That is not the query of the error message

Comment: `Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)` means that the credentials you are using for your mysql user are invalid, I suggest you check those first.

Comment: can't be ... the credentials get me into the database no problem

Comment: You are correct ... I failed to include the "require 'keygen-connect.php';" line to my php. The error I get  now is "Could not make key"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both "keys" and "key" are reserved words and need backquoting.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `keys` (`key`) VALUES ('".$key."')";
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/keywords.html

Comment: This worked ... thank yo so much. Such an easy fix! I should have spotted that

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in your database connection.
Check the user name and the password you provide to connect to the database.

Just write a sample code only to connect to the database.

Comment: Ok ... I see that I failed to add "require 'connect.php';" to the php file ... now it connects but I get this error "Could not make key"

Comment: Insert statement fails